# Select several latest values for different IDs

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
serialNumber  value masterID
1             red   500
1             blue  501
2             red   502
2             green 503
2             black 504
```

I need a single query that returns the following

```
serialNumber  value
1             blue 
2             black
```

I mean, I need the latest data that was inserted in the table for each serialNumber. MasterID is an incremental identity (PK).

I only managed to retrieve the last value for a single row (using top 1 and order by masterid desc) but I need to retrieve lot of data and making a query for each serialNumber is not viable.

Thanks!

Comment: Add SQL engine and version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select your Max(MasterID) from a subquery, then join the results back to the table to get the value for that max(masterId):

```
SELECT t1.serialNumber,
    value,
    masterID
FROM TABLE t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(masterID) AS maxid,
        serialNumber
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY serialNumber
    ) t2
    ON t1.masterid = t2.maxid
        AND t1.serialNumber = t2.serialNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `SQL SERVER` then try this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()
                  OVER(
                    partition BY serialNumber
                    ORDER BY masterID DESC) rn,
                serialNumber,
                value,
                masterID)
SELECT serialNumber,
       value
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn = 1
```